# There is a straight solution for difference equation $f(x+1)=\beta(x)f(x)$ such that $\beta(1)=a$ and $x>1$?

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

Recently, I stock in find a general or special solution of a difference equation  $f(x+1)=\beta(x)f(x)$ such that $\beta(1)=a$ and $x>1$. I do not know much about this group of equations so any name, link, paper,...  can helpful to me. I want to know more about this equations.

Comment: Do you assume anything about the solutions? Because as written, it is easy to construct solution by defining it piecewise on intervals $(n,n+1]$.

Comment: You have $f(n)=a f(1)\prod\limits_{i=2}^{n-1} \beta(i)$

Comment: I need a continuous function solution, so can I interpolate this?

Comment: There are infinitely many such functions. Simply consider $f(x)=\cos(2\pi x)g(x)$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you know nothing about $\beta$, then $f(n)$ can be just about any sequence you want, so long as $f(2)=a\cdot f(1)$.

More strictly, the following is true:

> Let $f_n$ be a piecewise constant nonzero function on all intervals $[n,n+1)$, that is, let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers, and let $f(x)$ equal $a_n$ on $[n,n+1)$. Let $a_2=a\cdot a_1$. Then, there exists a function $\beta$ such that $f(x+1)=\beta(x)\cdot f(x)$ for all $x$.

You can easily see this is true by simply defining $\beta(x)$ to equal $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ on $[n,n+1)$

Comment: $\beta(x)$ can be any function and in a special case, for instance, if $\beta(x)=s$, so $f(x)=\Gamma(x)$. I want to find welldefind solutions.

Comment: @JamalFarokhi If $\beta$ can be any function, then $f$ can also be any function.